# How to store other language in LiteDB?

Tags: c#, litedb

I am making a quiz game with C# in which I wanna store Korean as question . I'm not sure that It is storing Korean but when I fetch data then it show like ??? instead of Korean characters , so what I can do to show or use Korean character in my program?

Comment: Can you add some more information? What have you tried? You mention SQLlite. Is the code saving already? What is the table structure. Etc

Comment: I'm using LiteDB in which I'm storing my questions in Korean.When I fetch my data to display in Console or Label of the Form , It shows (???) i don't know how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue will be around the code page being used.
You can test the encoding with this pragma:

PRAGMA encoding;

Note that you can’t change the encoding for an existing database. You will need to create a new database with a specific encoding then open a SQLite connection to a new file.

Then:

PRAGMA encoding = "UTF-8";  // change as needed

You’ll need to recreate the schema / structure and import all the data.